# Javascript help handling mouseclick in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to get my inputhandler to work in Javascript.
What

In my Game.update I currently have this code:

```
this.Update = function() {
    if (input.GetMousePressed()) {
       console.log(input.GetMousePosition());            
    } 
}
```

And this is my inputhandler:

```
function InputHandler(canvas) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.mousePressed = false;
    this.mouseDown = false;
    this.mousePosition = new Position(0, 0);

this.GetMousePosition = function() {
    return this.mousePosition;
}

this.SetMousePosition = function(event) {
    var rect = this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.mousePosition = new Position(event.clientX - rect.left, event.clientY - rect.top);
}

this.GetMousePressed = function() {
    return this.mousePressed;
}

this.canvas.onmousedown = function(event) {
    input.mouseDown = true;
    input.SetMousePosition(event);
}

this.canvas.onclick = function(event) {
    input.mouseClicked = true;
    input.SetMousePosition(event);
}


window.onmouseup = function(event) {
    if (input.mouseDown == true) {
        input.mousePressed = true;
        input.mouseDown = false;            
    }
}
```

The first problem is that I dont know how to handle mousePressed and set it to false. Now it stays true forever.

I'm quite new to Javascript and I'm thankful for any change that would make this better or cleaner code or if what Im doing is bad practice.

I'm using addEventListener for normal button pressing and maybe I should for this to?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need `mousepressed`/`mouseup` and `click` events. The only difference between successful pressed/up and `click` is that click target should be the same element.

So I would either use the first option or the last but not both.

Your `mousePressed` flag is set to `true` because it gets assigned true value once you press the mouse. You need to reset it back to `false` at some point.

Usually, you don't even need this flag since you trigger whatever function you need inside `mousepressed` event. Not sure why you would save the information that this happened, do you use it somewhere else?

Also, yes using `addEventListener` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      body {
        background-color: black;
      }
      
      canvas {
        position: absolute;
        margin: auto;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        border: solid 1px white;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script type="application/javascript">
    
    var imageWidth = 180;
    var imageHeight = 160;
    var canvas = null;
    var ctx = null;
    
    var mouseDown = false;
    var mouseX = 0;
    var mouseY = 0;
    var bounds = null;
    
    function canvas_onmousedown(e) {
      mouseDown = true;
    }
    
    function canvas_onmousemove(e) {
      if (mouseDown) {
        mouseX = e.clientX - bounds.left;
        mouseY = e.clientY - bounds.top;
      }
    }
    
    function canvas_onmouseup(e) {
      mouseDown = false;
    }
    
    function loop() {
      ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
      ctx.fillRect(0,0,imageWidth,imageHeight);
      
      if (mouseDown) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
      } else {
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
      }
      
      ctx.fillRect(mouseX - 25,mouseY - 25,50,50);
      
      requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }
    
    window.onload = function() {
      canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      canvas.width = imageWidth;
      canvas.height = imageHeight;
      canvas.onmousedown = canvas_onmousedown;
      canvas.onmousemove = canvas_onmousemove;
      canvas.onmouseup = canvas_onmouseup;
      
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
      
      requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }
    
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```